# Crear Diccionarios de listas en Python

Tags: python, array, json, diccionarios

Buen día, Estoy trabajando con diccionarios de listas de diccionarios en Python. Pero al momento de hacer el llenado no me crea una lista nueva con sus respectivos datos, si no que envía los datos a una única lista
Quiero que se guarde cada cliente con sus respectivos datos, pero se guarda un único cliente con todos los datos

*Me gustaría saber como podría arreglar este error de llenado*. Todo en la opción 1 del programa

```
import os
import json
from pathlib import Path

diccionario = dict()
o = 0
Articulos = []

file = Path("DicPrueba3_0.json")
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    resp = int(input("Programa de registro de productos. \n 1.Registrar \n 2.Reporte \n 3.Eliminar \n 4.Salir \n >> "))
    if resp == 1:
        os.system('cls')
        print("Registro de articulos.")
        o += 1
        print("Ingresaremos los datos de articulo", o)
        diccionario["Cliente"] = ("Cliente",o)
        
        p = {'Nombre': input("Ingrese el nombre del articulo: "),
             'CProduccion': float(input("Ingrese el costo de produccion: "))}
        p['Utilidad'] = ((p['CProduccion'] * 20) / 100) + p['CProduccion']
        p['Impuesto'] = ((p['CProduccion'] * 15) / 100) + p['Utilidad']
        p['PVenta'] = p['CProduccion'] + p['Utilidad'] + p['Impuesto']
        
        Articulos.append(p)
        for d in Articulos:
            diccionario['Datos'] = Articulos
        print("Articulos",Articulos)
        
        input()
        print(diccionario)
        input()
        file.write_text(json.dumps(Articulos))

    elif resp == 2:
        print('%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s' % (
        'Articulo','Costo de Produccion','Utilidad','Impuesto','Precio de venta'))

        for d in json.loads(file.read_text()):
            print('%-20s %-20.2f %-20.2f %-20.2f %-20.2f' %
                (d['Nombre'],d['CProduccion'],d['Utilidad'],d['Impuesto'],d['PVenta']))
            
        input()
```

Comment: Creo que tienes que inicializar `Articulos=[]` en cada iteración del `while`

Comment: Podrías poner como te salen los datos? Porque al probar tu código, según te entendí, me sale lo que buscas